# Crashing App Due to Core Data Segue Transfer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am loading content into a UITableView Controller from a Core Data model and am wanting to be able to press on a data point and have it open the edit mode (another view controller) and populate the UITextFields with the data. Currently, the app crashes when I press on a cell in the table, throwing this exception:

```
[UINavigationController setDevice:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc548f20
2014-07-07 20:23:37.157 MyApp[20241:1250380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setDevice:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc548f20'
```

Here is the code for preparing the segue to transfer data:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Update"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"1");
        destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
        NSLog(@"2");

    }
}
```

I believe the issue is because I have a navigation controller as my destination for the segue, when it should really be the view controller connected to the navigation controller. How do I fix this?

**ADDED**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Update"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"1");

        UINavigationController * nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        SecondViewController * vc = nvc.viewControllers[0];

        destViewController.device = selectedDevice;

        NSLog(@"2");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Update"])
        {
            NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
            UINavigationController * nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
            SecondViewController * vc = nvc.viewControllers[0];
            vc.device = selectedDevice;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My app is still crashing with your added code. I have edited the question to show my new attempt.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You should assign selectedDevice to vc instead of destViewController since vc is a SecondViewController while destViewController is UINavigationViewController @C-O-D-E